# Processing UTF-8 characters in text file in java

Tags: java, parsing, utf-8, substring, tagging

I've a text file which contains the following sample UTF-8 text:

```
ኣእምሮኣዊ/ADJ ጥዕና/N ።/PUN

ቅድሚ/PRE ብዙሕ/ADJ ዓመታት/N “/PUN ኣእምሮኣዊ/ADJ ስንክልና/N ብጋኔን/N ወይ/CON እከይ/ADJ መናፍስቲ/N ኢዩ/V_AUX ዝመጽእ/V_REL “/PUN ዝብል/V_REL ግጉይ/ADJ ኣመለኻኽታ/N ነይሩ/V_GER ።/PUN

ከም/CON ውጺኢቱ/N ድማ/CON ኣእምሮኣዊ/ADJ ስንክልና/N ዘጋጠሞም/ADJ ኣባላት/N ናይ/PRE ሓደ/NUM ሕብረተ-ሰብ/N ብኣሰቃቕን/ADJ ኢሰብኣውን/ADJ ኣገባብ/N ይተሓዙ/V_IMF ነይሮም/V_AUX ።/PUN
```

Lingpipe implementation of HMM POS Tagger for Brown Corpus:

`BrownCorpus` class reads the zipped POS Corpus as follows:

```
public class BrownPosCorpus implements PosCorpus {

    private final File mBrownZipFile;

    public BrownPosCorpus(File brownZipFile) {
    mBrownZipFile = brownZipFile;
    }

    public Parser<ObjectHandler<Tagging<String>>> parser() {
    return new BrownPosParser();
    }

    public Iterator<InputSource> sourceIterator() throws IOException {
    return new BrownSourceIterator(mBrownZipFile);
    }

    static class BrownSourceIterator extends Iterators.Buffered<InputSource> {
    private ZipInputStream mZipIn = null;
    public BrownSourceIterator(File brownZipFile) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(brownZipFile);
        mZipIn = new ZipInputStream(fileIn);
    }
    public InputSource bufferNext() {
        ZipEntry entry = null;
        try {
        while ((entry = mZipIn.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            if (entry.isDirectory()) continue;
            String name = entry.getName();
            if (name.equals("brown/CONTENTS") 
            || name.equals("brown/README")) continue;
            return new InputSource(mZipIn);
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // ignore and close and return null
        }
        Streams.closeQuietly(mZipIn);
        return null;    
     }
    }
}
```

The BrownPosParser.java class parses the zipped brown pos corpus as follows:

```
public class BrownPosParser
     extends StringParser<ObjectHandler<Tagging<String>>> {

    @Override
    public void parseString(char[] cs, int start, int end) {
        String in = new String(cs,start,end-start);
        String[] sentences = in.split("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length; ++i)
            if (!Strings.allWhitespace(sentences[i]))
                processSentence(sentences[i]);
    }

    public String normalizeTag(String rawTag) {
        String tag = rawTag;
        String startTag = tag;
        // remove plus, default to first
        int splitIndex = tag.indexOf('+');
        if (splitIndex >= 0)
            tag = tag.substring(0,splitIndex);

        int lastHyphen = tag.lastIndexOf('-');
        if (lastHyphen >= 0) {
            String first = tag.substring(0,lastHyphen);
            String suffix = tag.substring(lastHyphen+1);
            if (suffix.equalsIgnoreCase("HL")
                || suffix.equalsIgnoreCase("TL")
                || suffix.equalsIgnoreCase("NC")) {
                tag = first;
            }
        }

        int firstHyphen = tag.indexOf('-');
        if (firstHyphen > 0) {
            String prefix = tag.substring(0,firstHyphen);
            String rest = tag.substring(firstHyphen+1);
            if (prefix.equalsIgnoreCase("FW")
                || prefix.equalsIgnoreCase("NC")
                || prefix.equalsIgnoreCase("NP"))
                tag = rest;
        }

        // neg last, and only if not whole thing
        int negIndex = tag.indexOf('*');
        if (negIndex > 0) {
            if (negIndex == tag.length()-1)
                tag = tag.substring(0,negIndex);
            else
                tag = tag.substring(0,negIndex)
                    + tag.substring(negIndex+1);
        }
        // multiple runs to normalize
        return tag.equals(startTag) ? tag : normalizeTag(tag);
    }

    private void processSentence(String sentence) {
        String[] tagTokenPairs = sentence.split(" ");
        List<String> tokenList = new ArrayList<String>(tagTokenPairs.length);
        List<String> tagList = new ArrayList<String>(tagTokenPairs.length);

        for (String pair : tagTokenPairs) {
            int j = pair.lastIndexOf('/');
            String token = pair.substring(0,j);
            String tag = normalizeTag(pair.substring(j+1));
            tokenList.add(token);
            tagList.add(tag);
        }
        Tagging<String> tagging
            = new Tagging<String>(tokenList,tagList);
        getHandler().handle(tagging);
    }
}
```

The problem is the following bug occured while parsing the UTF-8 corpus:
The key problem is in the BrownPosParser.java:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

[java]     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)

[java]     at BrownPosParser.processSentence(BrownPosParser.java:72)
```

The STACK TRACE is given below:

```
 C:\Lingpipe-Ver-4.1.2\Experiments\NER\posTags>ant eval-brown
 Buildfile: C:\Lingpipe-Ver-4.1.2\Experiments\NER\posTags\build.xml

 compile:

 [javac] Compiling 11 source files to C:\Lingpipe-Ver-4.1.2\Experiments\NER\posTags\build\classes


 eval-brown:

 [java] COMMAND PARAMETERS:

 [java]   Sent eval rate=5

 [java]   Toks before eval=1000000

 [java]   Max n-best eval=32

 [java]   Max n-gram=8

 [java]   Num chars=128

 [java]   Lambda factor=8.0

 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

 [java]     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)

 [java]     at BrownPosParser.processSentence(BrownPosParser.java:72)

 [java]     at BrownPosParser.parseString(BrownPosParser.java:20)

 [java]     at com.aliasi.corpus.StringParser.parse(StringParser.java:71)

 [java]     at EvaluatePos.parseCorpus(EvaluatePos.java:123)

 [java]     at EvaluatePos.run(EvaluatePos.java:75)

 [java]     at EvaluatePos.main(EvaluatePos.java:183)

 [java] Java Result: 1
```

Which part of the code should I modify to properly parse the UTF-8 pos corpus?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: And the question is? What is the connection between your text file and the two classes? What is going wrong, what do you expect instead?

Comment: That is a nice example of Ge'ez script (used in Ethiopia). But I fail to see any question in your post. What do you want to know?

Comment: What is `InputSource` ?

Comment: The problem is that the two classes works with Latin-1 characterset. I coudn't parse the UTF-8 characters in text file. Which part of the code should I modify to properly parse the UTF-8 pos corpus?

Comment: It doesn't look like anything to do with UTF-8. Rather, it seems like you have an extra space somewhere in the file, or a pair without a `/`.

Comment: I have seen it. It's not becuse of the extra spaces but I think it;s due to the inablity of parsing the utf-8 text corpus. Here is the key problem in the BrownPosParser.java class.  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1                                                                                                                [java] at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)                                                                                                                    [java] at BrownPosParser.processSentence(BrownPosParser.java:72)

Comment: Well, I saw that in the question already. This indicate that it didn't find a `/`. The reason it wouldn't find a `/` have nothing to do with encoding - a `/` would still be in ASCII even if the Ge'ez words were gibberish. The reason it wouldn't find a slash is that either there is a pair without a slash in the file, or that there are two consecutive spaces, or a space at the beginning or at the end of the line, in which case you get an empty token.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @RealSkeptic , I got your point. I will try to look at it.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt waiting for your comments after question modification.

Comment: @user3359138 The problem doesn't seem to be in my areas of expertise.  Doesn't seem to be directly related to utf8 or unicode, which is why I looked at it.

Comment: Writing Python or Java REs to locate consecutive spaces, a space at the beginning or at the end of the line in the corpus as per all of your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it solves your issue; but to set the charset change this line:

```
mZipIn = new ZipInputStream(fileIn);
```

to

```
mZipIn = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fileIn), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Check also if there are some empty lines in your file. 

p.s Kemey?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comment @Eritrean - Ertrawi Hawey (Eri bro). I will check it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Locate and eliminate consecutive spaces, a space at the beginning or at the end of the line and check that all tokens have the / in the corpus.

It works.